# How do precordial leads measure electrical changes in the heart?

Tags: human-physiology

In precordial leads the electrodes from limbs are connected to a common point via resistors. What is the potential at the common point?

Comment: For those who post without using spelling checks I would suggest a change of heart.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, the "title" of your question doesn't seem to match the "body". ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 